# Cant pass ajax variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this code of html, the part that says Cliente is filled with a simple mysql query; what i want to do is that when you select one option in Cliente it automatically displays the options in the second list that are linked to cliente in the database.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Cliente</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="cliented" name="cliented" class="form-control">
      <?php foreach ($dcli3 as $key) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key['id'] ?>"><?php echo $key['nombre'] . ' ' . $key['apellido'] ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Cuenta</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="cuentad" name="cuentad" class="form-control">
      <?php foreach ($dcu as $key) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key['numero'] ?>"><?php echo $key['numero'] ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

To get the selected option in the first list i do it with this js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="cliented"]').change(function(){
        var cliented = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'cons.php',
                data: cliented,
                dataType: 'json',
         });
    });
});
```

Everything is fine until that point, even if i use alert(cliented); it shows me the id that corresponds to the selected client.
The problem is when i make the query like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['cliented'])) {
$cliente = $_POST['cliented'];
$cu = "SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE idc= '$cliente'";
$dcu = $conn->query($cu);
}
```

The $cliente variable is always empty. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

You want to send a key/value pair. Right now all you are sending is the value

Change:

```
 data: cliented,
```

To:

```
 data: {cliented: cliented},
```

Comment: what exactly *"didnt work"*? that is not a very descriptive statement

Comment: The variable $cliente in the file cons.php is still empty, the solutions by hans and kevin didnt help either. Maybe the data isnt reaching the file cons.php....

Comment: How are you checking that? You don't have a success callback do you? i hope you aren't trying to open that other url directly and check that way

Comment: No, but the second list is not populating. I know opening that file to check would be useless because at that moment the variable shouldnt be loaded, only when i select an option in the first list.

Comment: Well what is shown should work... try dumping `$_POST` and do nothing else. Also add proper error and success handling. Can also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see exactly what is sent

Comment: If i dump $_POST i get this: array(0) { }

Comment: I've made a small adjustment. Try it please. Else it could be that there is an error somewhere else. Not on your provided code

Comment: I have done ajax this same way for many years. Something else is wrong. Did you inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see the exact data being sent??

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value to a key.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name="cliented"]').change(function () {
        var cliented = $(this).val();
        var postData = {
            cliented: cliented
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'cons.php',
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'json',
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select[name="cliented"]').change(function(){
    var cliented = $(this).val();

    DATA = 'cliented=' + cliented;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'cons.php',
            data: cliented,
            dataType: 'json',
                 success:function()  
                 {

                 }
     });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting variable name with the ajax.

Change:

```
data: cliented,
to:
data:'cliented='+cliented
```